# ADFS Sign-In Pages Customization

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, adfs

I am working on  a iOS application.

The login page which is showing from ADFS on a UIWebview is not looking good, so I want to customise it.

Is this possible from the client side?

I have tried to get user inputs in a custom login field and autofill the web view form and submit so that user can't see the ugly login screen which is coming from ADFS itself, but I am not getting the desired result. I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should not interfere with the presentation of the ADFS login process.

Presentation of an unmodified ADFS site helps the user confirm that they are entering their credentials into their organisation's federation portal.

An important part of the federation model is that an untrusted party (such as your app) does not have access to the user's credentials, only the token that results from credential validation.

Organisations can (and should) customise the ADFS form branding on the ADFS server.

Answer (score 0):

The ADFS login-page is served out of ADFS.

You cannot customise it client side.

To customise on the server side, refer [ADFS : Continuing the Login and Home Realm Discovery (HRD) and Change Password customisation adventure](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2017/06/adfs-continuing-login-and-home-realm.html) .